# Optimization Problem: Fitting Hexagons within a Domain

Tags: python, optimization, geometry, android-3.0-honeycomb, tessellation

I have a geometry problem and I thought of using python to solve it (I have little experience). I need advice on how to approach the problem.

[hexagons fitting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuXW0.jpg)

In the annex you can see the problem. I have a domain L x B and given the cell size of a hexagon (Ls), I found the maximum number of cells in straight (n) and zig zag (m) directions to cover the domain, staying within it. ErrorL and errorB are the errors that I commit between the boundary of the domain and the cells, since I have an integer number of cells to use, and this error should be minimized.

Here the simple code (maybe is possible to obtain it much simpler, but it works)

```
from scipy import optimize
import numpy as np

#case cells in L straight (n), in B zig zag (m)

L = 500
B = 200
Ls = 10
Lz = Ls*(3**(0.5)/2)

print('Ls =', Ls)
print('Lz =', Lz)
print('-------------')

def errorL(n):
    return abs(L-(Ls*n + Ls/2))

def errorB(m):
    return abs(B-(Lz*m + Lz/3))

resultL = optimize.minimize_scalar(errorL)
resultB = optimize.minimize_scalar(errorB)

a = round(resultL.x)
b = round(resultL.x)-1
c = round(resultB.x)
d = round(resultB.x)-1

if (Ls*a + Ls/2) <= L:
    print('n =', a)
    print('errorL =', errorL(a))
else:
    print('n =', b)
    print('errorL =', errorL(b))

if (Lz*c + Lz/3) <= B:
    print('m =', c)
    print('errorB =', errorB(c))

else:
    print('m =', d)
    print('errorB =', errorB(d))
```

This was an example with a given cell size Ls, now I would like to find a way to mantain Ls within a range [a,b] and find the best Ls, n and m to minimize errorL and errorB.
Each minimization of errorL and errorB depends on two variables, but the choice of Ls affects both.
I started writing a minimization problem with two variables but I am not sure how to proceed considering errorL and errorB to minimize with the same variable Ls. Furthermore I would like to work only with n and m as integer numbers. How can i do it?

Any suggestions is welcome.

Thank you very much

dr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At constant `Ls`, you need not to solve an optimization problem in order to fine `m` and `n`. You can simply set:

```
n = floor((L-Ls/2)/Ls)
m = floor((B-Lz/3)/Lz)
```

and the errors will become:

```
errorL = L-(Ls*n + Ls/2)
errorB = B-(Lz*m + Lz/3)
```

and of course `Lz` is equal to `sqrt(3)/2*Ls`

So, both error values become functions of only a single variable i.e. `Ls`. Now you can define a single cost function (for example `errorL*errorB` or `errorL+errorB`) and minimize it w.r.t. `Ls`.